# Results from many dropdown lists

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Sample Scenario: Sheet 1 has 15 lists and each list has multiple dropdown options.

Sheet 2: I need to have the results from the options chosen on the lists on sheet 1 divided by lists.

So if on the dropdown menu on sheet 2 I choose - List Hobbies, it's going to give the options I choose on sheet 1 for that list as a text.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: Welcome! I just want to clarify: does [**this book**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qP8IqgzgHcckX0Teal9JeKZXg1Bo_MQ40eIWo5BIzJo/edit?usp=sharing) match your description of the problem? Or when you say "15 lists", do you mean 15 options for the source of the second dropdown?

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Patricia, your scenario isn't as clear and unambiguous as it could be. Would you please edit your question to include some sample data, as well as an example of how a successful outcome would appear.  Would you also describe any work you did to solve your own question or research a solution. Lastly, you have described what you are trying to do, but what EXACTLY is the problem that you are having.